# How can I make this Oracle SQL query More efficient and less redundant to avoid a "snapshot" error on large datasets?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to improve my skills querying large data sets.

I want payments during a specific date range with an 'xyz' paycode,
where the "id1" is not 0 and not null, and if there are more than 13 payments to a specific "id1" This should be in the result of my query.

I feel like I'm being redundant querying the payment table twice, but I'm not sure how to get the id1 count and the payments with the specific paycode in a single query.

If I run this on a lot of data it's extremely slow and will not complete. I get a "snapshot" error.

**All the table / data relations are indicated correctly in my joins / queries below, but how can I make this more elegant and more performant?**

```
SELECT
    emp.emp_fname first_name,
    emp.emp_lname last_name,
    pmt.id1,
    pmt.id2,
    pmt.pay_date,
    pmt.pay_key,
    pmt.check_num,
    case.file_num
FROM

/*query to collect all valid id1s that occur more than 13 times */
    (
        SELECT
            id1
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    id1,
                    COUNT(*) AS cnt
                FROM
                    payment pmt
                WHERE
                        pay_key IN (
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                pay_key
                            FROM
                                allotment
                            WHERE
                                pay_code = 'xyz'
                        )
                    AND
                        id1 <> 0
                    AND
                        id1 IS NOT NULL
                    AND
                        trunc(pmt.pay_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')
                    AND
                        upper(TRIM(deleted) ) = 'N'
                GROUP BY
                    id1
            )
        WHERE
            cnt > 13
    ) ptxids

    /*join these to full-payment records with matchinig id1s during this time*/
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            payment
        WHERE
                upper(TRIM(deleted) ) = 'N'
            AND
                id1 <> 0
            AND
                id1 IS NOT NULL
            AND
                trunc(payment.pay_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')
    ) pmt ON pmt.id1 = ptxids.id1

    /*join on allotments where pay_key matches and allotment pay_code is xyz*/
    INNER JOIN allotment alt ON
        upper(TRIM(alt.deleted) ) = 'N'
    AND
        alt.pay_code = 'xyz'
    AND
        alt.pay_key = pmt.pay_key
   /*join on case to return the requested file-num*/
    INNER JOIN case ON case.event_num = alt.event_num
  /*join on emp to return payee / employee name */
    INNER JOIN  emp ON emp.event_num = case.event_num;
```

Comment: Without and diagnostic data, any answers would be a guess. If you can post a SQL Monitor report, then we can see where time is being spent and see where the query can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This join:

```
FROM

/*query to collect all valid id1s that occur more than 13 times */
    (
        SELECT
            id1
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    id1,
                    COUNT(*) AS cnt
                FROM
                    payment pmt
                WHERE
                        pay_key IN (
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                pay_key
                            FROM
                                allotment
                            WHERE
                                pay_code = 'xyz'
                        )
                    AND
                        id1 <> 0
                    AND
                        id1 IS NOT NULL
                    AND
                        trunc(pmt.pay_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')
                    AND
                        upper(TRIM(deleted) ) = 'N'
                GROUP BY
                    id1
            )
        WHERE
            cnt > 13
    ) ptxids

    /*join these to full-payment records with matchinig id1s during this time*/
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            payment
        WHERE
                upper(TRIM(deleted) ) = 'N'
            AND
                id1 <> 0
            AND
                id1 IS NOT NULL
            AND
                trunc(payment.pay_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')
    ) pmt ON pmt.id1 = ptxids.id1
```

can be eliminated with a help of `count(*) over` analytic function. Just one subquery:

```
 FROM
 /*query to collect all valid id1s that occur more than 13 times */
        (
            SELECT pmt.*,
                COUNT(*) Over( Partition by id1) AS cnt
            FROM
                payment pmt
            WHERE
                    pay_key IN (
                        SELECT 
                            pay_key
                        FROM
                            allotment
                        WHERE
                            pay_code = 'xyz'
                    )
                AND
                    id1 <> 0
                AND
                    id1 IS NOT NULL
                AND pmt.pay_date >= TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') 
                AND pmt.pay_date < TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')+1
                AND
                    upper(TRIM(deleted) ) = 'N'
        ) xx
    WHERE
        xx.cnt > 13
```

Some minor changes:

- removed redundant `DISTINCT` from the subquery
- removed `trunc(pmt.pay_date)` because it prevents RDBMS from using an index
  on this column

Comment: cant just add +1 to the date, this will pick up any rows at midnight on the 2-oct-2017

Comment: @Ab Bennett yes, you are right, the condition should be `pmt.pay_date < TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')+1` but not `<=`, I've changed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

some initial ideas

1.) remove trunc on payment.pay_date as this will disable index usage on this column. if no index on this column add one.

```
trunc(payment.pay_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')
```

make it

```
payment.pay_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')+(86399/86400)
```

2.) remove distinct on the query on the inside of the IN

```
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ pay_key FROM allotment WHERE pay_code = 'xyz'
```

make sure there is an index on pay_code as well. In fact any reference directly to pay_code = 'xyz' make sure there is an index on that column.

Without going into complete detail put an index on any column that has high selectevity, ie < 10% of rows. Combine these columns into the same index on the same table.

Remove any function on a column as this renders the index useless.

3.) Add a having clause to this part of your query to stop returning data that you just want to filter out anyway

```
            SELECT id1
            FROM payment pmt
            WHERE pay_key IN (SELECT pay_key
                              FROM allotment
                              WHERE pay_code = 'xyz'
                     )
                AND id1 <> 0
                AND id1 IS NOT NULL
                AND pmt.pay_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND 
                                       TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')+(86399/86400)
                AND upper(TRIM(deleted) ) = 'N'
            GROUP BY id1
            having  count(*)>13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this select :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
      COUNT(pmt.id1) OVER(PARTITION BY pmt.id1) cnt,
      emp.emp_fname first_name,
      emp.emp_lname last_name,
      pmt.id1,
      pmt.id2,
      pmt.pay_date,
      pmt.pay_key,
      pmt.check_num,
      case.file_num
  FROM payment pmt
  INNER JOIN allotment alt ON alt.pay_key = pmt.pay_key
        AND UPPER(TRIM(alt.deleted) ) = 'N'
        AND alt.pay_code = 'xyz'
  INNER JOIN case ON case.event_num = alt.event_num
  INNER JOIN  emp ON emp.event_num = case.event_num
WHERE     pmt.id1 <> 0
      AND
          pmt.id1 IS NOT NULL
      AND
          TRUNC(pmt.pay_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-17') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-17')
      AND
          UPPER(TRIM(pmt.deleted)) = 'N'
) A
WHERE A.cnt > 13;
```

TRUNC(pmt.pay_date) and UPPER(TRIM(pmt.deleted)) in where clause are not use the index(es), If they are exist on pay_date and pmt.deleted columns.

Comment: you can't remove the trim though and get the same behaviour